# Saving an imageView, image, and a background image to camera roll?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimageview, uitextview

In my view controller, I have an imageview, a textview underneath, and a background image?

I want to capture all of this as an image, and have it sent to the camera roll

If there is a way, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your All Images and text View put in different UIView and set outlet for this view & then write this code in your view Controller..

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.saveview.bounds.size, NO, 1.0f);

[self.saveview drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.saveview.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;}
```

Replace this **saveview** with your **UIView** name.

Use of this method is..

```
    UIImage *sourceImage=[self screenshot];
```

Then Save to your Camera Roll like that..

```
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourceImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Hope this is helpful for you..

Answer (score 1):

Igor's answer is correct but renderInContext is quite slow. Replace that with the more modern (iOS 7 +) API:

`[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] afterScreenUpdates:NO];`

In my testing that method is over 50% faster.

Comment: Is there a way other than using UIGraphics...? Because, I am getting a couple of errors: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 error, and Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

Comment: That usually means your context is NULL or it's size hasn't been set. You can also do ```snapshotForView:inRect``` on your view but it returns a UIView not a UIImage.

Comment: you got my up vote sir, because i didn`t know about this

Comment: Thanks @Igor.Mursa. I  only discovered it a few days ago when I needed to improve performance in my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
   [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
   UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

This function of code will create you a image from the view that you will pass,example if you will give it self.view it will create a image with every element on the self.view and after that it will save it to photo album,

Comment: Is there a way other than using UIGraphics...? Because, I am getting a couple of errors: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0 error, and Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died